# why can IPv6 ping reach other interfaces?

Tags: linux, ping, ipv6, vlan, network-interface

I have an eth interface setup with VLAN 100 & VLAN 200. I have a client that sends pings on VLAN 200 only.
For some reason, it lets me ping the VLAN100 interface IP from the client but only if I ping the IPv6 address, not the IPv4 address.

The IPv6 addresses are global dynamic(IPs assigned by `radvd`)

`2020::100:5aef:68ff:feb4:f8f7/64`(Vlan100)

`2020::200:5aef:68ff:feb4:f8f7/64`(Vlan200)

and I have normal `10.x` addresses assigned as IPv4.
I am surprised that I can ping the IPv6 address of the VLAN100 interface (while I clearly see with wireshark that the frames are entering with the 200 Q-tag on the `.200` interface). There seems to be some internal switching between the interfaces happening. Can anyone explain?

IP forwarding is disabled also:

```
sysctl net.ipv{4,6}.conf.all.forwarding
net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding = 0
net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding = 0
```

I'm obviously still pretty new to IPv6, also.

I'm using ARCO Linux (which is an Arch Linux derivative)

Comment: I'm actually more surprised that it doesn't let you ping the IPv4 address.

Comment: @user1686 why? it's a different IP on a different iterface (even if virtual) - and I would assume that the same applies to IPv6 also but it does not

Comment: Linux considers IPv4 addresses as belonging more to the host than to specific interface (and by default will even respond to ARP queries on "wrong" interfaces), something like the "weak host model". The association with specific interfaces is actually slightly stronger in IPv6, but still only slightly.

Comment: Do you have IP forwarding enabled on the host? (That is, `sysctl net.ipv{4,6}.conf.all.forwarding`)

Comment: @user1686 Really, interesting regarding the IP- interface association, especially because an IP gets associated with a MAC and a MAC is associated with an interface. I'll have to look up "weak host model". And no, IP forwarding is disabled (also updated OP)

Comment: "an IP gets associated with a MAC" is an oversimplified way to look at it. *Other* hosts associate your IP with your MAC, based on ARP replies that they receive. But on *your own* host, that's not the case. Locally the association is with an interface first, and the MAC address doesn't enter the picture until after the decision to answer the ARP query is made. Indeed, many interface types don't even have MAC addresses...

Comment: @user1686 true, true! Yes and there's also MAC chips that can respond to ARP requests all by themselves without any further SW processing (decision making) but I feel like this discussion (while interesting) is getting off track here :)